# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' But numpy module already installed

Tags: python, numpy, modulenotfounderror

Error:
[image]
I have already installed numpy module(`pip show numpy`):

[image]
this how it shows when i try to install numpy again
[image]

I tried to import numpy module which is already installed but it throws ModuleNotFoundError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using `vs code` you need to select the Python interpreter explicitly:

1. press `ctrl+shift+p` to open the editor command
   [image]
2. then Search `Python: Select Interpreter`
3. then you can choose the appropriate Python interpreter
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a classic case of multiple Python versions on the same machine.

Try a

```
pip --version
```

as well as a

```
python -m pip --version
```

and a

```
python --version
```

my guess is that the associated versions of Python are different (note the pip version won't be the same as the Python version: `pip --version` on my machine gives: `'pip 22.3.1 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)'`). This is often the case where the user has an installed version, and the system comes with a version too; Macs often have this problem, for example.

My thoughts are to try

`python -m pip install numpy`

which should use a version of pip associated with the Python version you are using. If you want to play more with multiple Python versions, I recommend using pyenv or conda, which will allow multiple versions to be installed simultaneously with a better-defined separation.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**
The ModuleNotFoundError occurred due to the incorrect installation of multiple Python versions(python 2.7,3.8.0,3.11.3) on my computer as @notastringtheorist mentioned.
**How I Fixed it:**

1. Uninstall all Python versions currently installed on your computer.
2. Create a dedicated directory for Python installations, such as "C:\Python".
3. Install a specific Python version into a subfolder within the "C:\Python" directory. For example, you can name the subfolder "Python_3.8.0" for Python 3.8.0. If you want to install another Python version, create a different subfolder within the same directory, such as "Python_3.11.3" for Python 3.11.3.
4. Set the PATH environment variable to include the path of the desired Python version's subfolder and the path of the "Scripts" subfolder inside it. Make sure to add a double backslash at the end of each path.
5. Move up both the subfolder path and the script path of the Python version you want to use in the PATH variable.

> It's important to note that this solution assumes you're using a
> Windows operating system. Additionally, managing multiple Python
> versions manually can be complex and may lead to conflicts. Consider
> using a Python version manager like Anaconda or pyenv to handle
> multiple Python installations more efficiently and avoid potential
> issues. 
> **check this youtube Video**:https://youtu.be/ggRsauJcEyE